# How to use django autocomplete with field related to ContentType?

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

Good day, I am using **django-autocomplete-light 3.2.10** for field that is related to `ContentType` model with `ForeignKey` relation inside django admin. I need to filter `ContentType` over its name but it is really a `@property`. So is there a way to do this?

**Update:** I needed actually to filter `ContentType` over models' `verbose_name` instead of a `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer, it's a little bit ugly but working.

```
class TransactionAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated() and user.is_staff:
            if self.q:
                models = apps.get_models()
                result_list = []
                for model in models:
                    if self.q in model._meta.verbose_name:
                        result_list.append(
                            ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model)
                        )
                return result_list
            else:
                return ContentType.objects.all()
        else:
            return ContentType.objects.none()
```